# Swagger Document for complex nested JSON

Tags: swagger, microservices, swagger-2.0, rest

Using `Swagger 2.0`. My API response is below and I have to make swagger document for it:

```
{
  "id": "012",
  "det": [
    {
      "rec1": {
        "det1": "ok",
        "det2": "notok"
      },
      "rec2": {
        "det3": "ok"
      }
    },
    {
      "rec1": {
        "det1": "bad",
        "det2": "good"
      },
      "rec2": {
        "det3": "poor"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Array `det` has two objects. I am able to create a document depicting the first object of this array. But while showing the second one, it gives all sorts of errors like duplicate mapping, object mapping issues, etc.

I am not using the `example` way of doing it. Instead, doing it in YAML style using `$ref`.

Any guidance would be helpful.

YAML:

```
TestModel:
            type: object
            properties:
              id:
                type: string
                example: "012"
              det:
                type: array
                items:
                    $ref: '#/definitions/Rec'
        Rec:
          type: object
          properties:
            rec1:
              type: object
              properties:
                det1:
                  type: string
                  example: "ok"
                det2:
                  type: string
                  example: "notok"
            rec2:
              type: object
              properties:
                det3:
                  type: string
                  example: "ok"
```

Comment: Can you post your YAML?

Comment: updated the question with YAML